# why keep getting this error: zsh: permission denied

Tags: terminal, zsh

I'm trying to access my directory folder using the Terminal, but I keep getting this error:

```
Last login: Thu Mar 16 11:57:11 on ttys000
(base) kaylalei@Kaylas-MacBook-Air ~ % /Users/kaylalei/Kayla_EU
zsh: permission denied: /Users/kaylalei/Kayla_EU
(base) kaylalei@Kaylas-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I have tried Get Info at Sharing & Permission and allow Terminal to Full Disk Access, but still get the above error. I don't know what else is causing this problem. Please help/advise about this issues. Thanks!

I'm trying to access my directory folder using the Terminal command line.

Comment: Are you trying to change working directories? If so, you likely have not enabled the `autocd` option in your `.zshrc`.

Comment: Doesn't look like a programming problem to me. Maybe you should ask that question at an admin board like superuser

Comment: The error message means that `/Users/kaylalei/Kayla_EU` either does not have read- or execute-permissions. So check those. If they are OK, and if Kayla_EU is a script, also check its #! line.

Comment: Thinking of it, another possibility is that `/Users/kaylalei/Kayla_EU` is a directory.